# MySQL query doesn't show results properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. One of my tables with `users` is:

```
id         name     longitude       latitutde  
-----      -----    -----------    -----------
1          Mark     -82.347036     29.6545095
2          John     -82.357036     29.665095
3          Paul     -82.367036     29.645095
4          Dave     -82.337036     29.675095
5          Chris    -82.437036     29.575095
6          Manny    -82.538036     29.745095
7          Fred     -82.638036     29.346095
```

I'm using SQL to detect nearby people:

```
 SELECT id, 
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) *
             cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-122) ) +
              sin( radians(37) ) * sin(radians(latitude)) ) 
             ) AS distance
    FROM `users` HAVING distance < 50 ORDER BY distance DESC LIMIT 20`
```

The other `matches` is like this:

```
id         sender    receiver        status  
-----      -----    -----------    -----------
1            3           4              0
2            1           5              1
3            6           3              1
4            2           6              0
5            2           1              0
```

Where sender is the person who sent the invitation receiver is the person who receives is.

My Query:

```
SELECT
a.id
,a.distance
FROM
  (Select  
       id,
       st_distance_sphere(POINT(-82.337036, 29.645095 ),
                          POINT(`longitude`, `latitude` ))/1000  as distance
    FROM
        users u  
    WHERE id <> 1 
    HAVING distance < 5000 
    ORDER BY distance 
    DESC LIMIT 20) a
WHERE
    a.id in (SELECT `sender` FROM matches WHERE status = 1)
    OR a.id NOT IN ( SELECT `sender` FROM matches
           UNION ALL SELECT `receiver` FROM matches )
ORDEr BY a.distance ASC
```

My fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95972531a390a013796ed4cf7ad99884

In matches table Id 1 have match only with Id 5 (where status is 1).

The part with:

```
       a.id     in ( SELECT `sender` FROM matches WHERE status = 1)
    OR a.id NOT IN ( SELECT `sender` FROM matches
           UNION ALL SELECT `receiver` FROM matches )
```

is wrong somewhere, because it has to show id 2,3,4,6,7 not only 6 & 7 . Check out last query in fiddle

The query must be with logic:

If I am the `sender` with id 1 don't return me `receiver`(`a.id`).

If I'm `receiver` with id 1 return me `sender`(`a.id`) where `status` = 0.

If I'm not `sender` or `receiver` return me `a.id`

Comment: The result match your query.

Comment: @Eric then why it didn’t show me 2,3 & 4 in fiddle ?

Comment: Because it's the logic you put in your `WHERE` statement.  The statement `a.id in (SELECT `sender` FROM matches WHERE status = 1)` will only return id 1 and 6.  That immediately filter out the rest.  Then in the outer query, you put another filter `WHERE id <> 1`.  So it just leaves with id 6.

Comment: @Eric Can you post the whole query as an answer please?

Comment: It's not an answer.  I am just telling you why id 2, 3, 4, 5 is missing.  You don't tell us what logic you want, so no one is able to help you.

Comment: @Eric the logic is described: The query must be with logic:

If I am the sender with id 1 don't return me receiver(a.id).
If I'm receiver with id 1 return me sender(a.id) where status = 0.
If I'm not sender or receiver return me a.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use your logic

You want:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.distance
FROM
    (SELECT 
        id,
            ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(- 82.337036, 29.645095), POINT(`longitude`, `latitude`)) / 1000 AS distance
    FROM
        users u
    WHERE
        id <> 1
    HAVING distance < 5000
    ORDER BY distance DESC
    LIMIT 20) a
WHERE
    a.id NOT IN (SELECT `sender` FROM (SELECT `sender` FROM matches UNION  SELECT `receiver` FROM matches) t1
WHERE `sender` IN (SELECT `sender` FROM matches WHERE `receiver` = 1 AND status = 1
UNION SELECT `receiver` FROM matches WHERE `sender`  = 1
))
ORDER BY a.distance ASC
```

```
id |           distance
:- | -----------------:
3  | 2.8991986256467865
2  |  2.946298180421104
4  |  3.335840468953696
7  |  44.20441197234838
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ecf86b9e822631868dd0792df83766d7)*

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d080c3563dbf9db0a1f36bcf795ec937 check out this. I've inserted in `matches` `(6, 6, 1, 1)` . Why I get id 6 ? It shouldn't return me id 6, if status is greater than 0

Comment: you have no rule for that.  in the logic you presented, but i also excluded every SENDER where 1 is the receiver and has status = 1

Answer (score 1):

```
   a.id     in ( SELECT `sender` FROM matches WHERE status = 1)
OR a.id NOT IN ( SELECT `sender` FROM matches
       UNION ALL SELECT `receiver` FROM matches )
```

The first part of the OR gets ids senders, hence ids, 1 and 6.

But the second part is even more incriminating.

```
SELECT `sender` FROM matches    -- 1,2,2,3,    6
UNION ALL 
SELECT `receiver` FROM matches  -- 1,    3,4,5,6
```

The `UNION ALL` is                     1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6.

The dups are ignored.

Meanwhile, a.id is some subset of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, depending on the distance arithmetic.  Hence the only a.id left from the second part of the `OR` is `7`.

So, I would expect to get 1, 6, and maybe 7.

Hmmm... I think I am getting lost, and I think you were getting lost.  Please change things so that there are not two `ids`, and 4 meanings of `1`.  `1` as a `status`, `1` as a sender/receiver, `1` as two different `ids`.  For example, make the matches.id between 11 and 16; make all the senders/receivers between 21 and 27.  Make the statuses `ON` and `OFF` (or something).